# Android Context used in classes other than Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-context

In my Mainactivity:

```
 LoginUser.loginUser(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(), getApplication());
```

So in my LoginUser class,
I want to start a dialog box like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).set.....
```

but failed,
get fault info like this:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Also I would like to use like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ABC.class)
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Also failed. And get fault info like this:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I am so confused about all of these, can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: please add full code how you are going to show dailog means where in activity or service or in fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure of what you're up to, but for the first problem, it looks like you're trying to use a non-activity context to show a dialog.

TL;DR, you cannot an AlertDialog with an application context, it requires an Activity.
Consider something like:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(<activity>)
```

The second problem is also similar, you can start an activity with an application context, but you need to start it as a new task. To do that, you need to add a flag. (Although, this is not considered to be good practice)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Check [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) for more about what you can and cannot do with various types of contexts in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
LoginUser.loginUser(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(),  Mainactivity.this);
```

replace getApllicationcontext() to your Activity.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(<activity>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well

```
LoginUser.loginUser(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(), this);
```

LoginUser.java

```
public void loginUser(Context context){
}
```